# is writing the permissions section of the manifest file really a headache for android developers?

Tags: android

I've seen research papers claiming that this is really a big problem, time-consuming trial-and-fail and error-prone. Is this really true?

Comment: It's a relatively minor one-time issue. You find out in testing pretty quickly if you've forgotten something. I can't say I spend a lot of time thinking about it, so it can't be that bad.

Comment: Of all the tasks that come with developing an Android app, this is the easiest.

Comment: I'd be very interested to see the "research papers" you're referring to, I've never found it to be a problem.

Comment: Do you have a link to these papers?

Comment: You're a PhD, and you didn't provide us with a citation? :O

Answer (score 2):

I'd be interested in a link to these "research" papers but the answer is no. Its fairly easy to deal with with the worse case scenario is getting a SecurityException and adding that permission in a nice GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know who said that. It is extremely easy to modify permissions. You just have to setup [uses permission](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html) in the manifest. Here is a [list](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) of all documented permissions on Android.

Comment: Actually, the claim is that the developers are not 100% sure what permissions are needed for their application or the required set of permissions could change as the application evolves. Thus, the development life cycle is basically try something that seems right, get "Operation not permitted" errors, and add the missing permissions. And these steps have to repeat several times whenever the application changes affect the required set of permissions.

Answer (score 0):

**Not a headache , but a lost of time yes** . I think in my opinion , that if the integration with eclipse could be better if it interacts the same like when you need a new lib for creating and X type instance object.

The good part , is that you know everytime what parts your program can use of your mobile .